# drupal_add_js not working

Tags: 7, ajax, routes, javascript

I have this code in my javascript:

```
(function ($) {  
    Drupal.behaviors.myid_print_table_id_link = {
        attach: function (context, settings) { 
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST', 
              url: '?q=myid_print/table_pager',                                      
              success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);                          
              }                                                 
            }).done(function(o) {                  
              console.log(o);                                
            });
        }
    }  
})(jQuery);
```

This calls a function called `myid_print_table_pager` declared in my hook menu:

```
 function myid_print_menu(){

     $items = array();
     $items['myid_print/table_pager'] = array(
         'title' => 'Table Pager',
         'page callback' => 'myid_print_table_pager',       
         'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
     ); 
     return $items;
  }
 }
```

Below is my function:

```
function myid_print_table_pager(){
    drupal_add_js('$(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });', 'inline');
    watchdog('message', 'I've been here!');
}
```

I'm pretty sure that the function `myid_print_table_pager` is invoke because `'I've been here!'` is seen in my `watchdog` table in my database. But why does the alert with the message `Hello!` has not been invoke?

Comment: Try this: `drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });', 'inline');` `$` is just an alias for `jQuery`. Maybe it is overwritten.

Comment: @Huelfe --> That doesnt work either...

Comment: Maybe you should try to return something from your page callback, like `return array('#markup' => 'Hello world');`. I'm not sure if Drupal handles the page correctly if you don't provide the main page content.

Comment: @marcvangend --> How will I do that exactly?

Comment: Just add that line at the end of the page callback. See my answer below also.

Answer (score 3):

I usually avoid calling `drupal_add_js()` and use the `#attached` property of the render array. The advantage of using #attached is that you don't need to implement additional hooks, the js is only added when needed, and (as I've been told) it works better with caching. Your code would look something like this:

```
function myid_print_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['myid_print/table_pager'] = array(
    'title' => 'Table Pager',
    'page callback' => 'myid_print_table_pager',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}


function myid_print_table_pager() {
  $build = array(
    '#markup' => 'Hello world!',
    '#attached' => array(
      'js' => array(
        array(
          'data' => '$(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });',
          'type' => 'inline',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $build;
}
```

Disclaimer: untested code, please let me know if it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You'ld better use [hook_page_build](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7) to add your JS.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_build().
 */
function MYMODULE_page_build(&$page) {
  drupal_add_js('
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

      console.log("Hello!");
      // Do your magic here:

    });', 'inline');
}
```

Comment: What I really want is to invoke a function, inline.

Comment: @Aliyah – Updated answer.

Comment: Not working either, I just put myid_print_page_build. I want to alert Hello after an ajax call. Where am I missing?

Comment: Well, that's no Drupal Question then. Better ask that on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function myid_print_table_pager(){
     drupal_add_js('(function($){$(document).ready(function(){alert("Hello!");});})(jQuery);', 'inline');
     watchdog("message", "I've been here!");
}
```

And

```
(function ($) {  
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Drupal.behaviors.myid_print_table_id_link = {
            attach: function (context, settings) { 
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST', 
                  url: '?q=myid_print/table_pager',                                      
                  success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);                          
                  }                                                 
                }).done(function(o) {                  
                  console.log(o);                                
                });
            }
        }  
    });
})(jQuery);
```